# Unable to test angular2 karma with angular-cli and ng2-material

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-material, angular-cli

@angular 2.4.5, @angular-cli 1.0.0-rc.1, karma 1.4.1, @angular/material 2.0.0-beta.2

I'm not able to get to first base running ng test with a simple application that contains material design code.

**//account-edit.component.html**

```
<mat-card tdMediaToggle="gt-xs" [mediaClasses]="['push']" [@transition]="pageState">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>{{accountForm.get('accountName').value}}</span>
    <span flex></span>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <mat-card-content class="push-bottom-none">
    <form [formGroup]="accountForm">
      <div layout="row">
        <mat-input-container flex>
          <input mdInput
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="Account Name"
                 formControlName="accountName"
                 [focus]="inputFocused">
          <mat-hint align="start">
            <span [hidden]="accountForm.get('accountName').pristine || !accountForm.get('accountName').errors?.required" class="tc-red-600">Account name is required</span>
            <span [hidden]="accountForm.get('accountName').pristine || !accountForm.get('accountName').errors?.maxlength" class="tc-red-600">Maximum length is 50 characters</span>
          </mat-hint>
          <mat-hint align="end">{{characterCount("accountName")}} / 50</mat-hint>
        </mat-input-container>
      </div>
      <div layout="row">
        <mat-input-container flex>
          <input mdInput
                 type="text"
                 placeholder="Status"
                 formControlName="status">
        </mat-input-container>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-button [disabled]="!accountForm.valid" color="primary" (click)="save()">SAVE</button>
    <button mat-button (click)="openConfirm()">CANCEL</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

//account-edit.component.spec

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { AccountEditComponent } from './account-edit.component';
import { MaterialModule } from "@angular/material";

describe('AccountEditComponent', () => {
  let component: AccountEditComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AccountEditComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ AccountEditComponent ],
      imports: [MaterialModule],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AccountEditComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

// Karma Spec-List

```
Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'mediaClasses' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-card'.
1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component and it has 'mediaClasses' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("<mat-card tdMediaToggle="gt-xs" [ERROR ->][mediaClasses]="['push']" [@transition]="pageState">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>{{acco"): AccountEditComponent@0:32
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <mat-card-content class="push-bottom-none">
    <form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="accountForm">
      <div layout="row">
        <mat-input-container flex>
"): AccountEditComponent@7:10
Can't bind to 'focus' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("         placeholder="Account Name"
                 formControlName="accountName"
                 [ERROR ->][focus]="inputFocused">
          <mat-hint align="start">
            <span [hidden]="accountForm.ge"): AccountEditComponent@14:17
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'mediaClasses' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-card'.
1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component and it has 'mediaClasses' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
 ("<mat-card tdMediaToggle="gt-xs" [ERROR ->][mediaClasses]="['push']" [@transition]="pageState">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <span>{{acco"): AccountEditComponent@0:32
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
  <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  <mat-card-content class="push-bottom-none">
    <form [ERROR ->][formGroup]="accountForm">
      <div layout="row">
        <mat-input-container flex>
"): AccountEditComponent@7:10
Can't bind to 'focus' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("         placeholder="Account Name"
                 formControlName="accountName"
                 [ERROR ->][focus]="inputFocused">
          <mat-hint align="start">
            <span [hidden]="accountForm.ge"): AccountEditComponent@14:17
    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:9877/base/src/polyfills.ts?cfbbd9932b8de37e7e2bb2d6bc6b813677eb5dd9:24495:33)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:107390:16)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:9004:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:25187:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:77984:68)
    at http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:77867:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:77867:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:77769:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9877/base/src/polyfills.ts?cfbbd9932b8de37e7e2bb2d6bc6b813677eb5dd9:23837:26)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:180937:39)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9877/base/src/test.ts?cb11aab543fb05b4ed5bf4b4760f4f7c2197d07c:181639:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9877/base/src/polyfills.ts?cfbbd9932b8de37e7e2bb2d6bc6b813677eb5dd9:23836:32)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:9877/base/src/polyfills.ts?cfbbd9932b8de37e7e2bb2d6bc6b813677eb5dd9:23629:43)
    at http://localhost:9877/base/src/polyfills.ts?cfbbd9932b8de37e7e2bb2d6bc6b813677eb5dd9:24216:57
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks!